# Polymer paper-input imperative key-bindings

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm trying to bind the enter key on a paper-input by specifying:

```
<paper-input class="flex" key-bindings="[[keys]]"></paper-input>
```

and the following properties on the host element:

```
keys: {
            type: Object,
            value: function() {
              return {
                'enter': this._addVariant
              };
            }.bind(this)
          }
```

also tried this version:

```
keys: {
            type: Object,
            value: function() {
              return {
                'enter': '_addVariant'
              };
            }.bind(this)
          }
```

Both do not work and I can't find any references on google. Does somebody know what I'm missing? Maybe the `keyEventTarget`?

Comment: Please try to explain what you exactly trying to do, there may able to solve in another way.

Comment: What I'm trying to do, is to just fire up the ```_addVariant``` function when the paper-input has focus and the enter key get's pressed.

I know other ways to solve it, e.g. add the ```IronA11yKeysBehavior``` to my element or add a ```on-tap``` property where I check the pressed key code by myself.

But I'm just curious how to use the ```keyBindings``` property which is documented on the element: https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-input/elements/paper-input#property-keyBindings

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a different way then you look for. But it works, what is the pressed key is:

```
   <paper-input value="{{vall::input}}" on-keydown="_keyEvets" label="Arıyorum">
  </template>
  <script>
    class MyTest extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'test-component'; }

      static get observers() {return ['checkVall(vall)']}

      checkVall(v){
        console.log('vall :'+ v);
      } 

      _keyEvets(k) {
        console.log('_keyEvets',k.code);
      }
    }
```

Here is link to a [sample](http://jsbin.com/raranog/edit?html,console,output)